# Javascript stop scrolling on touchmove after scrolling has already started

Tags: javascript, scroll, event-handling, preventdefault, touchmove

I have a simple example where a user starts to scroll on a touch screen, and then after one second, I want to disable scrolling.  I thought event.preventDefault() would stop the scrolling but it doesn't seem to work after scrolling has already started

Here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/7s5m8c6L/30/

```
let allowScroll=true;

function TS(e){//touchstart handler
  setTimeout(function(){
    allowScroll=false;
  },1000)
}

function TM(e){//touchmove handler
  if(!allowScroll){
    e.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

In this example, you can start scrolling, and after a second, I want the scrolling to stop, but it does not.  I know there are ways that I can get this to work with CSS (adding overflow:hidden), but I would particularly like to know why preventDefault doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using chrome, there is a hint in the console:

> [Intervention] Ignored attempt to cancel a `touchmove` event with `cancelable=false`, for example because scrolling is in progress and cannot be interrupted.

The problem is exactly that [`Event.cancelable`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/cancelable). Unfortunately for you this property is read-only and it is not safe to call `preventDefault` for a not cancelable event. If you print `e.cancelable` in the `TM` function you can observe that throughout the scrolling `e.cancelable` is false.